Risk of lightning strike with wire antenna in tree?
I'm considering putting up a long wire antenna across my yard for reception / DX purposes. Due to how my yard is set up I think one good way of putting it up would be with a metal mast on a secondary building and then to a nearby tree near my house. So the feed point would be on the tree.
My question is if this increases the risk of lightning strikes? The metal antenna can be grounded and the risk there can be reduced. But I don't really know if you can ground a tree like that.

@Dereck NEC sounds like a Canadian or US standard? I think it's worth noting that the installation standards depend on the country!

I'm afraid I can't see how building regulations answer my question regarding the risk of lightning strikes.

Once upon a time nearly every house had a giant metal antenna sticking up above the roofline to pull in signals from that now-passe thing called TV. Sure, lightning might strike it, or it might strike the tree nearby, or... Even purpose-designed lightning rods don't always get preferentially struck. Disconnect the antenna outside the house if bad weather is coming in.

It is commonly claimed that lightening rods do not "attract" lightning or increase the chances of a lighting strike. However, I have not seen a definitive reference. If true, this would seem to imply that your antenna wire will not increase the risk of a lightning strike. But it might very well increase the amount of damage (i.e. to your radio) if a lightening strike does occur.

Don't worry about increasing chances of getting struck by lightning.  Just assume it is going to happen and take precautions.  Ideally, a grounded lightning arrestor like a gas discharge tube at building ingress.  Less ideally would be 4-6 loops of coax near the ground at building ingress.  That's the minimum, other precautions may help.
